Is there a helper method from the new web3.js library to convert a public Key to string
Is there a helper method from the new web3.js library to convert a CryptoKey into a base58 string
export const { privateKey, publicKey } = await createKeyPairFromBytes(
    keypairBytes
);


Yep, getAddressFromPublicKey
const addressBase58 = await getAddressFromPublicKey(publicKey)

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/functions/_solana_addresses.getAddressFromPublicKey.html
